# How to give count down for OTP in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer, countdown, one-time-password

I need to give 60 sec time countdown for resend otp. and if i click verifyOtp butn then count down to be stop. and i want that otp to be expaire. in count down time resend otpbutton to be disable.. please suggest me how to set count down for resendotp.

i am getting otp in registrService().

```
    do{
                var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
                let regUserStatus = json["status"] as? String

                if regUserStatus == "sucess"
                {
                    print("the json regggggggggggis \(json)")
                    let phNum = json["mobile_number"] as? Int
                    let status = json["status"] as? String
                    self.otpField = json["otp"] as? Int
                }
                else{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.registerButton.isHidden = false
                        self.sendOtpButton.isHidden = true
                        self.otpTextField.isHidden = true
                        self.resendButn.isHidden = true
                        self.otpcountLabel.isHidden = true
                        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "user exist", in: self)
                    }

                }
            }
```

resendButton .

```
   @IBAction func resendOtpButn(_ sender: Any) {
    print("resendotp tapped")

    registerService()
   }
```

Comment: Not sure I can understand your question.  Is the process:  send request and start 60 seconds timer, then after 60 secs resend the request, but if the resend button is pressed before 60 seconds stop the time and send the request immediately?

Comment: @flanker, i am getting otp in regButton, if i click regButn countdown need to be start like 0.59, 0.58...0. if in count 0, i need otp to be expire... i have one resendOtpbut, her i am calling regServc() if i click i will get otp, again countdown to be start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have started the OTP process you need to create a 60 seconds timer that when it expires it runs a selector method:

create a class level Timer property:

```
var otpTimer: Timer?
```

create the timer when your reg button is clicked

```
@IBAction func regButn(_ sender: Any) {
  registerService()
  startTimer()
}

func startTimer() {
  optTimer?.invalidate(). //cancels it if already running
  optTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(timerDidFire(_:)), userInfo: userInfo, repeats: false)
}
```

When your timer hits zero the selector will be called, and you can do whatever you want to do to expire the otp request

```
@objc func timerDidFire(_ timer: Timer) {

   // timer has completed.  Do whatever you want...
}
```

if the resend button is tapped, I think you want to restart the timer, so ...

```
@IBAction func resendOtpButn(_ sender: Any) {
  registerService()
  startTimer()
}
```

You will probably also want to cancel the timer if your otp completes successfully, so in your success completion handler you can just do

```
self.optTimer?.invalidate()
```